# Suppose that $a \subset R$. Show that the following are equivalent. a). A is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose that $a \subset R$. Show that the following are equivalent.

a). A is closed.

b). If $[a,b]$ is a closed interval for which $A \cap [a,b]$ is non-empty then $sup(A \cap [a,b]) \in A$ and $inf(A \cap [a,b]) \in A$.

$a \rightarrow b$: Since A is closed, and $[a,b]$ is a closed interval, their intersection must be closed. Since A is closed, it is obvious that $sup(A \cap [a,b]) \in A$ and $inf(A \cap [a,b]) \in A$

$b \rightarrow a$: Since we know that $sup(A \cap [a,b]) \in A$ and $inf(A \cap [a,b]) \in A$, that means A is a closed interval, hence A is closed.

Can someone check my reasoning?

Comment: Let $A=[0, 1]\cup[1, 2], a=0, b=2$. Then the infimum and supremum of the intersection are $0$ and $2$, respectively, but $A$ is not an interval.

Comment: Okay, suppose $A$ is not closed, so it can't be the whole real line. We may suppose it is bounded from above by some $b\in\mathbb{R}$, so that $\sup A=b$, but $b\not\in A$. Then the intersection $[b-1, b]\cap A$ is non-empty, but the supremum (namely, $b$) is not in $A$. Bounded from below is similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implication a. to b. is correct, provided that you are allowed to use that a bounded closed set contains its sup and inf.

From b to a: suppose $x \in \overline{A}$ and $x \notin A$. Then there is a monotone sequence (increasing or decreasing) $(a_n)$ from $A$ that converges to $x$. If the sequence is increasing, use the interval $[a,b]:=[a_1, x]$ and note that $x = \sup(A \cap [a,b])\notin A$ contradicting the property we assumed on $A$. If decreasing use $[a,b]:=[x,a_1]$ and its infimum.

Answer (score 1):

a -> b is not obvious and looks like double usage of a and b.
A $\cap$ [a,b] is closed and bounded, hence compact subset R.
Now show compact subsets of R have a max and a min.

b -> a.  Counter example.
a < b, A = (a-1, b+1).

Comment: That's not a counterexample. Statement 2. is $\forall a<b: ([a,b] \cap A \neq \emptyset) \to (\inf([a,b]\cap A)\in A \land \sup(A \cap [a,b]) \in A)$, so you cannot use $a,b$ as variables in the counterexample...

Comment: It is not. @HennoBrandsma.  As no quantification was  included, the variables are free.

Comment: "If $[a,b]$ is a closed interval etc." clearly implies that $a,b$ can be anything, as long as that condition is satisfied. It's an implicit universal quantifier.

Comment: Such sloppy use of quantifiers  was not clear to three people.   Frankly more attention is needed for quantifiers and wffs.  "For all a < b" is a restricted quantifer of one variable "a"and a free variable "b" unless one prefers to make non-well form formulas.  @HennoBrandsma

Comment: There is a difference between mathematical language and formal logic.

Comment: In which case, don't use formal logic symbols for mathematical statements.  They repleately get abused even though they relieve ambiguity.